# How could i make a firestore cloud function trigger on user login?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Cloud functions doesn't accept onLoging by default, how can i "bypass" this limitation so i can run a cloud function every time a user gets "online".

My thought so far is to run a create document on logIn and listen to it, but what happens when the user is not login in but using his last time session?

Do i run the same post request on the isLogged function ? that function can be run many times when the application is running, so is not optimal.

is running the function on app init (angular 7) the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Only you can define what a "session" is for your app.  There is no universal definition that you can use to trigger a Cloud Function.  Firebase Authentication won't help with this either, since users are logged in "forever", until your code explicitly logs them out (it automatically refreshes the user's auth token every hour).

You're going to have to write your own code to figure this out by whatever specification you decide the user has "logged in" or "logged out".

Comment: figured that out, going to use an http call for the function in the end.

Answer (score -1):

> You can create a function that triggers when a Firebase user is created using the functions.auth.user().onCreate() event handler:

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events?hl=en-419

**but one alternative you have would be , to make a write operation in the client when user login.**

Comment: You can code a script to make the operations one time, to get the neccesary data,  if you need move data.

Comment: i would need it one time every time the user comes online

Comment: It's not possible from the server-side.
look this: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/firebase-auth